# RubyMine 7 not auto refresh project folder to update new file

Tags: rubymine, rubymine-7

I installed RubyMine 7 on ubuntu 14.04. When create file by using rails generate, rubymine not auto refresh tree folder to update new file in project folder. So can't open file or do something. I always click sync folder by hand T.T. But when i use rails destroy to delete some file, rubymine refresh folder tree when click back to it.